# Recreating a financial year with dates, works in excel but not in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I am trying to recreate something like this picture:
[image: Financial Year in excel]

But I just found out that the **cell B7 does not work**, the **cell B7** contains the formula:

> =IF($A$3="Financial Year",((CONCATENATE(B9,$C$3))-DAY(CONCATENATE(B9,$C$3))+1),EDATE(Summary!$C$15,-11))

In the above **A3 cell** is the one where I choose **Financial Year**, **B9** is month **January**, **C3** is the cell with the calendar year **2020** and the **Summary tab** is the picture here:[Summary Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAOP.png) where cell **C15** is the starting date with the formula: **=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1**

**Error I am getting from Cell B7**:

> Function Day Parameter 1 expects number values. But "January" is a text and cannot be coerced to a number

Answer (score 0):

To overcome a similar problem with CONCATENATE in a sheet I am using I included the following expression (in a longer string):

```
TEXT(DATE($A$2;$A$3;$A$4);" MMMM")
```

where A2,A3,A4 contained YY MM DD respectively.

[image]

You'll need to adjust this to suit your circumstances, of course.